# Do .a library files work in both Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, .a

I have been given a .a library file for my project. I can see you can use .a for Windows and Linux, which is different to .dll and .so.

Will the same .a file work on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: "I can see you can use .a for Windows and Linux" are you sure about that? Tag description of `.a`: "A static library of object code in UNIX/Linux that can be used by the link editor to create an executable program. "

Comment: I wasn't so sure, but the "add library" wizard in Qt Creator gives an option to add ".a" libraries for windows.

Comment: `.a` files are intermediate files, produced by the compiler, consumed by the linker. They're not deployed directly on the target machine. Compiler switches control what platform the code in the `.a` file targets.

Comment: So does that mean you can use .a files to compile programs for both Windows and Linux, but the .a file needs to be specific to the platform you want to run? That would mean you need a separate .a files for windows and linux?

Comment: There's an even more fundamental problem here: Windows doesn't care about .a files. Windows doesn't come with a static linker. Windows _does_ come with a dynamic linker for `.DLL` files, though. Windows leaves static linking to compilers such as Mingw and Visual Studio. Different compilers can make different choices.

Comment: Makes sense as I am using MinGw